# DataContractSerializer - how to use it?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to find out, how implement serialization in C# for Windows Phone 8

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010191/using-datacontractserializer-to-serialize-but-cant-deserialize-back/) solution. But I have problem. I don't know how to use **DataContractSerializer**. When I put it to Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone, it highlights me it. I tried to add:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
```

but it doesn't correct the issue.

How correct this problem?

Comment: Do you have System.Runtime.Serialization added in references?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` to your project.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015198/1921754), DataContractSerializer has some changed behaviour on Windows Phone 8.

What do you mean by 'highlight it'?